# Изменение таблиц в Datagridview с combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Всем доброго времени суток! Я сделал смену таблиц с комбобоx, но при выборе ничего не выходит вот пример
Вот сам код:введите сюда описание изображения

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
 
namespace SewingFactory
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private SewingFactoryDataSet2 db  = new SewingFactoryDataSet2();
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>(5);
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
 
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                            break;
                        }
            }
        }
 
        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.fabricReportTableAdapter.Fill(this.sewingFactoryDataSet2.FabricReport);
 
        }
 
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            switch(i)
            {
                case 0: dataGridView1.DataSource = db.FabricReport.ToArray();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Вот что выходит при смене ячейки комбобокса]

Comment: Сперва сбросьте датасорс: `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;`. Потом назначайте новый источник данных.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не помогло

Comment: Значит у вас нет данных. Пустая таблица.